# Is there any way to emulate "macros" in c#?

Tags: c#, macros, code-contracts

I’m trying to make CodeContracts in C# look more like statements so i need a tool that allows me substitute some code before the compiler sees it, if there is no way to do it i guess a Visual Studio plug in would help too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trying to fight the syntax of a language like C# is simply a bad idea. The tools you use will fight back with determination.

Just go with the flow and stop trying to swim against the current. You'll soon get used to the syntax and it will make sense to everyone else who works with the code.

Comment: Also, using C# paradigms is nearly always better than relying on macros, which will only give you (and anyone else reading/using your code) problems down the road.

Answer (score 2):

You could always channel the code through a C++ preprocessor (like [mcpp](http://mcpp.sourceforge.net/)) before sending the code to the C# compiler. That would give you full power of C++ macros :)

I guess you could use a pre-build task to do that.

I use this approach in one project of mine (though it is not C#, but a quite different language, but I needed the C++ like macros).

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with the normal codecontracts ?

http://www.cauldwell.net/patrick/blog/CodeContracts.aspx

And

http://weblogs.asp.net/podwysocki/archive/2008/11/08/code-contracts-for-net-4-0-spec-comes-alive.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What about [expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx)?